# ajax post data not working on shared hosting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm very confuse for this problem ajax post data, on localhost working but on shared hosting not working. This is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#login").click(function(){
              alert('asdf');
                var page = "login"; 
                var username = $("#username").val().trim();
                var password = $("#password").val().trim();
                $.ajax({
                        url:'pages/content/input_query.php',
                        type:'post',
                        data:{page:page,username:username,password:password},
                        success:function(response){
                            var msg = "";
                            if(response ==1){
                                window.location = "index.php?pages=home";
                            }else{
                                $("#result").html(response);
                            }
                         }
                    });

            });

        });
```

and my code html is

```
 <form role="form" action="pages/content/input_query.php" method="post">
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="username" id="username" />
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" id="password" />
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">    
          <div class="checkbox icheck">

          </div>                        
        </div><!-- /.col -->
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat" id="login">Sign In</button>
        </div><!-- /.col -->
      </div>
    </form>
```

And I have add code **alert('asdf')** , but there are no alert message  every click the button. What is the problem. Please help me. Every answer I appricated

Answer (score 1):

Have you called jQuery on server?
Try calling from jQuery CDN.
Use this code:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#login").click(function(){
          alert('asdf');
            var page = "login"; 
            var username = $("#username").val().trim();
            var password = $("#password").val().trim();
            $.ajax({
                    url:'pages/content/input_query.php',
                    type:'post',
                    data:{page:page,username:username,password:password},
                    success:function(response){
                        var msg = "";
                        if(response ==1){
                            window.location = "index.php?pages=home";
                        }else{
                            $("#result").html(response);
                        }
                     }
                });

        });

    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try preventing the default action of the #login element and when you pass the POST type, you must use uppercases. Something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#login").click(function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
          alert('asdf');
            var page = "login"; 
            var username = $("#username").val().trim();
            var password = $("#password").val().trim();
            $.ajax({
                    url:'pages/content/input_query.php',
                    type:'POST',
                    data:{page:page,username:username,password:password},
                    success:function(response){
                        var msg = "";
                        if(response ==1){
                            window.location = "index.php?pages=home";
                        }else{
                            $("#result").html(response);
                        }
                     }
                });
        });
    });
```